# How to download binaries for glfw on linux

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile, glfw

I am trying to download glfw (on linux OS) so that in my project I can write `#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>` from any directory. I have downloaded the source code, for glfw3 however, I would like this header file to be accessible from any directory without having to explicitly specify symbolic links all the time. Is this possible for linux OS?

Comment: You should not need to download anything. Everything you could possibly need to develop OpenGL, including this library, is already included in your Linux distribution. I just checked, and glfw is already packaged for Fedora, for example, and I'm sure it's already packaged for your Linux distribution too, and all you have to do is follow your Linux distribution's instructions for installing packages. Modern technology, isn't it amazing?

Comment: "I would like this header file to be accessible from any directory without having to explicitly specify symbolic links all the time" - That's where using a proper build system enters the picture.